# Mariadb: Can't create/write to file '/var/tmp/#sql_c27_0.MAI' (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I trying to select or desc tables sometimes it works and sometimes I got:

> ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/var/tmp/#sql_c27_0.MAI'
> (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")

it worked and stop working.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like an apparmor / setenforce problem. I've seen this error when the system security is blocking mysqld from using an unauthorized directory. Did you try to change the `tmpdir` option recently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your disk is out of space. I'd recommend running the following commands to check to see if it has free space / free inodes:

```
df -h
df -ih
```

Comment: The error code is 2, not 28 (= no space left of device)